# IIS iis_iusrs disappeared on Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: .net, iis

I have a .Net service installed on a Windows Server 2012R2.

Today, the users have complain because they couldn not store more files on server, it should be permissions related. Right click on the folder -> secutiry and IIS_IUSRS does not exist anymore.

How can be this group deleted?, is it possible to restore it?

I have restored IIS service and machine with no luck.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special in the `IIS_IUSRS` group. Its a local group created with `NT Authority\IUSR` as a member. If its deleted you can just create it with the same name and with the above user in it. That's all. Nothing to restore. You will have to look into restore for folders that might have lost this group when deleted. By default the only place I know this group has permissions is the inetpub\wwwrtoot folder with read permissions.

Normally, as with any other user management feature you need admin privilege to delete this group. Did you check user management to see if the group is actually deleted from local machine or just removed from this folder?

Comment: As you said, it was just removed for the folder. 

Nobody touched folder's permission... do you know why it could have happened? It worries me.

Thanks